# Rename gerrit project

Tags: gerrit

As per the instruction provided in this [link](http://lifuzu.com/blog/2014/04/09/rename-repository-on-gerrit/) renamed one of the gerrit project. However now don't see this project changes in `Open, Merged, Abandoned` list. Something is wrong in the process of renaming?

Our gerrit version is - 2.13 and offline indexing will impact the productivity. Online is it possible to perform this particular `project` and `changes` indexing only?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try these two related options:

1. [gerrit index start](https://gerrit-documentation.storage.googleapis.com/Documentation/2.13.2/cmd-index-start.html)
2. [gerrit index changes](https://gerrit-documentation.storage.googleapis.com/Documentation/2.13.2/cmd-index-changes.html)

Note: your Gerrit version is really old, you should think seriously in an update to a newer one.